# Blur effect fixed to right edge of div with overflow-x:scroll content

Tags: html, css, background-image, gradient, blur

I'm want to create a blur over the right edge of visible content of a div with overflow-x:scroll

```css
.scroll {
  display:flex;
  overflow-x:scroll;
  position:relative;
  
}

.scroll div {
  margin:10px;
}

img {
  width: 200px;
}
.overlay {
  position: fixed;
  background : transparent;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(29, 33, 47, 0), #1d212f);
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width:100px;
  height:304px;
  filter: blur(2px);
}
```

```html
Some Content Above
    <div class="scroll">
   <div><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1566321925839-ee26bd257e1b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=334&q=80"/></div>
   <div><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1566321925839-ee26bd257e1b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=334&q=80"/></div>
   <div><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1566321925839-ee26bd257e1b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=334&q=80"/></div>
   <div><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1566321925839-ee26bd257e1b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=334&q=80"/></div>
   <div><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1566321925839-ee26bd257e1b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=334&q=80"/></div>
   <div><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1566321925839-ee26bd257e1b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=334&q=80"/></div>
   <div><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1566321925839-ee26bd257e1b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=334&q=80"/></div>
   <div><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1566321925839-ee26bd257e1b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=334&q=80"/></div>
   <div><img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1566321925839-ee26bd257e1b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=334&q=80"/></div>
   <div class="overlay">
   </div>
</div>
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k31of5ms/28/)

As you can see in the JS fiddle, the dark blur overlay shows on the right side of scroll images div (hover below images to see scroller), but not in the correct height above div.

I didn't find a way to set the overlay to be exactly above div.

I can't solve this with setting fixed px from top/bottom because the content above and below is dynamic.

How can I set the blur effect in the div "overlay" to be placed exactly above the right side of the div "scroll"?

Answer (score -1):

If you don't need to be able to click the content you can add a box-shadow to the container class and a z-index to the children.

```
.scroll {
   display: flex;
   overflow-x: scroll;
   position: relative;
   box-shadow: inset -80px 0 40px -55px #1d212f;
}

.scroll div {
   margin: 10px;
   z-index: -1px;
}
```